# Create Google Cloud instance with custom FreeBSD ISO

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, freebsd

I want to create a new Google Cloud instance with Hardenedbsd iso. Hardenedbsd is a FreeBSD based OS. I checked public documentation on https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image but I couldn't see FreeBSD on supported OS section.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/) works pretty well in [GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute), the upload procedure of a custom image or making your own is quite easy I would say even better than with AWS, therefore high are the changes the same could apply for [Hardenedbsd](https://hardenedbsd.org/), the only "trick" is that after you have your raw disk you need to use gnu tar to upload the image:

```
gtar -cSzf freebsd.tar.gz disk.raw
```

To create the `disk.raw` I use this script https://github.com/fabrik-red/images/blob/master/fabrik.sh (root on ZFS) to read more about the procedures you could check: https://fabrik.red/post/google/

For testing or getting an idea, you could try `FreeBSD 12.0`
https://github.com/fabrik-red/images/releases/download/12.0/disk.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried working with any *BSD on Google Cloud Platform so take my words with a grain of salt.
You could try booting the instance in rescue mode (if supported) and perform a dd to write the Hardenedbsd to the main disk.
You could also take a look on Packer from Hashicorp which is meant to create OS images to be deployed on the cloud.

https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/googlecompute.html

Comment: I don't think the packer part would work as you need a base image to work with...